# SpaCy Multiple TextCategorizer's in one pipeline

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I'm working with SpaCy and I want to know if there is way to include multiple text categorizers within one pipeline and keeps is predictions separated. I already was able to train the two categorizers separately, but I can't figure out if there is a way to merge both classifiers in one pipeline. My current implementation looks like the following snippet:

```
nlp.add_pipe(text_categorizer_1, last=True)
text_categorizer_1.add_label("MyLabelforCategorizer1")

nlp.add_pipe(text_categorizer_2, name="textcat2",last=True)
text_categorizer_2.add_label("MyLabelforCategorizer2")

# Train and validation code here

doc = nlp("My sample text")
print(doc.cats)
# doc.cats will contain an object with the categories and its  associated probabilities
# but this object mix the result of both classifiers
# {"MyLabelforCategorizer1":0.1, "MyLabelforCategorizer2":0.9}
```

I want to know if add two categorizers to a single pipeline is supported? Doing that can have a negative impact in the underlying model (The CNN neural network of SpaCy)? If there is not impact how can I get the results from each categorizer? is enough to take the max value for each label set?.